# ReservationNumber can no longer be used reliably to differentiate events

Tags: email, gmail, google-calendar-api, markup

I sent several emails in sequence with the same email subject but different reservationNumber, however, Gmail Markup treated all of them as 1 event, hence Google Calendar only shows 1 entry.

This issue is intermittent, and I have not found a pattern of occurrence.

My current work around is to ensure these email subjects are unique, and it seems to be working, however, in my opinion, according to Google's documentation, the reservationNumber should be the reliable way to differentiate different event.

1. Has anyone experienced the similar issue, or even resolved it without any workaround?
2. Has anyone got Google's response relating to the issue?
3. Now that they have moved their support to Stack Overflow, does anyone know a more efficient way to directly reach Google?

Comment: Can you please share what you have done so far? :)

Comment: I've updated the thread description, please review again. All I've done so far is to use different email subject, but I'd rather prefer NOT to use this solution